# With the JMeter Distributed Testing HTTP Response doesn't shows

Tags: jmeter

I have executed Distributed Test with 1 Slave Machine from the Master. Successfully connected to Slave from the Master as well as Test executed successfully.

**Issue:** Though Test Ran successfully, summary report shows Response Times, under View results tree it doesn't shows the Response Data . So I am not sure is it ran properly, I would like to see  the response data.

When I ran the same test with out distributed testing i.e on the Master machine it self, I see the Response data.

Not sure what went wrong

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [by design](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote_batching_config).

> Since JMeter version 2.9, default is **StrippedBatch**, which returns samples in batch mode (every 100 samples or every minute by default).
> You can set mode by configuring:
>
> ```
> mode=one of the possible modes below
> ```
>
> ....
> **StrippedBatch**
>
> Same as Batch but **strips Response from SampleResult**. Configured by properties num_sample_threshold, time_threshold and sample_sender_strip_also_on_error

So you either need to [set the `mode` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) to the one which doesn't have `Stripped` in its value, i.e. to `Standard` or add a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) and configure it what to store and where to store.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regular behaviour of JMeter in distributed mode.

See the « mode » property explained here which defaults to StrippedBatch:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote_batching_config

So if you want to see response, you can but the drawback will be performance impact.

You can switch it to Standard, Batch or Async